# Oracle 12c installation

Tags: oracle

I have Oracle 11g installed on my system and want to install 12c now. Read articles (Oracle docs and general) which suggest that I can do so in different homes. But, when I try to install 12c (12.1.0.1 release 1), it does not allow me to do so as it says "**oracle _home (in environment variables) already defined and does not match the path specified (during installation)**".
A search on this portal gives results that do not answer my query.

What path should I specify for software location (Oracle home) during installation? (It auto reflects the server path of 11g installed)
Do I need to manually add this specified path to Oracle_Home path (in addition to the already existing oracle home for 11g) in environment variables for the installation to auto-accept it and allow further installation?

How do I get around the installation?

Comment: Why are you so impatient: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48040027/installing-multiple-oracle-homes-on-the-same-machine ?

Comment: Do not execute oraenv or unset ORACLE_HOME, alternatively you can set it to your new home before executing the Installer.

Answer (score 1):

Docs don't just "suggest" that you "can" install into a new location.  It is *required*.  Two different installations must be in their own `ORACLE_HOME` directories.  And you do not "add" another path/directory to `ORACLE_HOME`. `ORACLE_HOME` specifies only one home/directory at a time.

To quote from [the Installation Guide](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/LADBI/inst_task.htm#LADBI7742) (emphasis mine):

> "Do *not* install Oracle Database 12c software into an existing Oracle
>   home."

Also, [the installation guide](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/LADBI/usr_grps.htm#LADBI7678) specifically says to unset `ORACLE_HOME` and several other environment variables before launching the OUI.

> If you have had an existing installation on your system, and you are
>   using the same user account to install this installation, then unset
>   the `ORACLE_HOME`, `ORACLE_BASE`, `ORACLE_SID`, `TNS_ADMIN` environment
>   variables and any other environment variable set for the Oracle
>   installation user that is connected with Oracle software homes.